# Should "sleep" and "sleeping" be synonymous?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I was posting my first question on this site, found [here](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1367/can-walking-past-my-cat-at-night-disturb-her-sleep), and I saw that there was a tag [sleep](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sleep) and a tag [sleeping](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sleeping). Now, these are really two tags for one meaning, but are not yet synonyms, so I was wondering if there was a reason that they were not.

Comment: I can't find any question tagged with [tag:sleeping]. If there is no question associated with a tag, it will remove itself after some hours.

Comment: Oh, really? Ok, I'm from Arqade, where I don't believe this is true.

Comment: @TheUgly see the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From time to time users go through and clean up the tags.

I removed the [sleeping](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sleeping) and replaced it with [sleep](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sleep). There were only a few questions with either tag. By removing the sleeping tag from two questions, it will die overnight.

Naming preferences have been  discussions on meta about how to form our tags eg plurals for pets [Should our pet tags be plural or singular?](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6/should-our-pet-tags-be-plural-or-singular), and [Should we clean up "pooping" and "droppings"?](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159/should-we-clean-up-pooping-and-droppings). I figure people prefered the word without the *ing*.

Synonyms can only be created if a user has high enough rep to create them (both in rep and score within that tag) and then the synonym needs to be voted on. [How can we create tag synonyms in these early stages?](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60/how-can-we-create-tag-synonyms-in-these-early-stages)